# Why rsync failed to copy all files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, copy, rsync

I tried to copy 17171 files, but whatever parameters I use, it always copied 17160 which 11 lost.

But same command for another directory, copied accurately. (16545 files).

I also tried use cp, but also lost 11 files.

When I check the folder with finder, it should be 17171 files there...

```
rsync -arvz src dst
cp src dst
```

Above is the command I've tried

Comment: Can you add the filenames of the files that did not copy.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest migrating this question to [unix.se] or perhaps superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a number of issues at play:

One of the more common issues is that the target filename is illegal on the remote system, for example trying to copy a file with a colon `:` in the filename from UNIX to Windows.

There may also be permission issues reading the files that are not copied, check the permissions here.

Finally, you could try zipping (or taring) the bunch of files into a single file, and transfer just that instead.  Typically you'll see the problem when unpacking that file on the remote system.

EDIT: Another thought - are the files that did not copy really-really large, too large to store remotely?

If you rsync with the `-P` option, it should only re-transfer files that were not copied.  It will also print progress, that should give you a better idea of what's not copying.

Comment: No, all of the files are small text files.

Comment: I'm so confused...Is there anyway to print which 11 files lost?

Comment: When i use -P, it prints 1501 files to consider, 1497 files to consider...(5 source folders), and the number of files to be considered is 17176 (17171+5) which should be correct, but only 17160 files copied.

Comment: What about something like: `find . -type f -exec rsync -Parvz {} dst \;` copying it file by file.  It wont preserve the directory structure, but should allow you to see which files are breaking.

Comment: @Kingsley I know it's been a while but did you find a solution?

Comment: @artnikpro - I basically listed all the issues I've ever faced transferring files with rSync.  It's typically rarely permissions, *nearly always* local filesystem limitations Vs remote.  Something like `ext4` on Linux handles a lot more than say `Fat32` or `NTFS` - legal characters (':', '*', etc.), file size limits (4GiB on Fat32), symbolic links, etc.  Android too has a broad set of illegal characters, e.g.: '!'.   But in EVERY case, I'd warrant that `rsync` shows an error message of some sort.